# how to invert keys and values in a YAML file (key : value)

Tags: regex, yaml

I have a big `.yml` translation file, in which I would like to invert the keys and the values.

**what I have :**

```
some english sentence : une phrase en francais
another one : une autre
```

**what I would like to get :**

```
une phrase en francais : some english sentence
une autre : another one
```

I'm sure there might be a bunch of easy regex to do so, but I could not figure out how to do this ...

*I dont search a script, just a regex*

Comment: Are all your keys and values so simple? In particular does none of the sentences have a `:` embedded? Like the valid YAML `'He said: "Some English sentence"': 'Il dit: "une phrase en francais"'`

Comment: I only had one containing double dots, I changed it manually. thats indeed something to care about

Comment: So after we all agreed that [parsing XML with regex is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/347964), we now try do parse YAML with regex instead?

Comment: I think your comment really helps, @flyx ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex:

```
(.*)\s+:\s+(.*)
```

The substitution:

```
$2 : $1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lU6eM4/2

Comment: Thanks, I had to invert 1 and 2 but its exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

you can start with a simple regex :

```
^(.*):(.*)$
```

^  = start of line

(.*) = first match group

: = catch :

(.*) = second match group

$  = end of line

Using for exemple notepad++ you can do :

search : `^(.*):(.*)$`

replace `\2:\1`

where `\2` :content of second match group
and where `\1` :content of first match group

This method work only if you sentence don't contain `:`